# Precompiled headers and editing header files

Tags: c++, visual-studio, precompiled-headers

I'm using a precompiled headers in my project.
precompile.h includes both *.h files I created and many *.h files from libraries that I never rebuild.

My question is that every time I edit one of my *.h files, it compiles the whole precompile.h file. This takes about 5 mins.
(compiling after editing only a cpp file only takes 1 second.)

I know this is how precompiled headers work, but is there anyway to separate my header files, so that compiler only compiles my files?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

*"...every time i edit one of my .h files..."* - this suggests that you should move out these headers from precompiled header. Precompiled headers should include only headers that rarely change.

Comment: Exactly: #include "stdafx.h" ... #include "myfile.h"

Comment: may i still put all my #include "xxx.h" in one big "myheaders.h" file?